# In the VSCode debug mode, is there a way to copy all the Locals variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you're debugging in VSCode, all your variables are visible on the top left. You can right click on any one of them to copy it, but is there a way to copy groups of them, such as all the Locals?

Another example is when the variable represents an object. If I copy that value I get a reference to the object (e.g. ). Is there a way to copy all the variables within it? It would be especially useful in the case of argparse when I want all the individual arguments, not a reference to the object.

Comment: I've seen examples for Javascript from the VSCode team where they're able to copy an entire object. 
I'm currently using powershell and am in the same position where it just copies the value presented by the object rather than the whole custom object